# Prevent div scrolling in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll

I have a div block which shouldn't be scrolled apart from the page when entire page is scrolled, so I used css property

```
pointer-events: none
```

I using parallax, so top position of image and title in section "first" is set by it, but when mouse scrolling on this block it affects the top position

```
<section id="first" data-type="background" data-speed="10"  style="pointer-events: none!important">
     <div> 
        <h1 id="title">TITLE</h1>   
        <img src="slider.png" id="slider-image" />
     </div>
 </section>
 <section class="second" data-type="background" data-speed="10" >
      ...
```

Disabling pointer events works fine for Chromium and Mozilla, but nothing happens in Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Please include enough code in your question to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) is an overview of supported browsers for the CSS pointer events. As you can see, there is an issue that chrome and IE have with your code:

> Moving the scrollbar on an object with pointer-events: none; works in Firefox, but doesn't work in either Chrome or IE.

One potential workaround is to follow [this guide](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/) on forwarding mouse events through layers.

You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474722/touchmove-pointer-events-none-css-doesnt-work-on-chrome-for-android-4-4-chro) helpful.